# How to set automatic ScrollViewer down in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I am working on a task in UWP Technology for data binding with using  Data grid Control. But the issue is ScrollViewer. I want ScrollViewer to scroll down automatically when ever add any New Item in Data Grid and last index Data Grid list should be Display new Item in Bottom.

Please find snapshot below I have shared:

[image: Data Grid snapshot]

Code:

```
<controls:DataGrid x:Name="dgNewBill" RowBackgroundEvenBrush="Black" RowBackgroundOddBrush="Black" ItemsSource="{Binding objStockIssueItemList}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="478" SelectionMode="Single" TabNavigation="Local" HeaderBackground="Black" Background="Black" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="12" Margin="0,0,0,0" Loading="dgNewBill_Loading" TabIndex="2" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto" KeyUp="dgNewBill_KeyUp" DoubleTapped="dgNewBill_DoubleTapped"> 
</controls:DataGrid>
```

Comment: Can you provide some code you use? Its not possible to see what the problem is, when we only have a screenshot of the output

Comment: ok tanic . i using one List in c# In the list i adding one by one item then after this list to bind in Data Grid property  Item Source .

Comment: Please edit your question instead of comment. And please add some code with a minimum working example of your case

Comment: <controls:DataGrid x:Name="dgNewBill" RowBackgroundEvenBrush="Black" RowBackgroundOddBrush="Black" ItemsSource="{Binding objStockIssueItemList}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Height="478" SelectionMode="Single" TabNavigation="Local" HeaderBackground="Black" Background="Black" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" Grid.Row="2"  Grid.ColumnSpan="12" Margin="0,0,0,0" Loading="dgNewBill_Loading" TabIndex="2"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto" KeyUp="dgNewBill_KeyUp" DoubleTapped="dgNewBill_DoubleTapped">    </controls:DataGrid>

Comment: Backend Code:    dgNewBill.ItemsSource = cartItems;                                      cartiems => Global list instance  , dgNewBill => DataGrid Name , itemSource => Property

Comment: How I said before: Please edit you question and dont post it in the comments. Are you sure, that you are in the UWP-environment? Because there is no DataGrid control there.

Comment: yes tanic i using UWP with thirdparty DataGrid Control Added .

Comment: And you dont think, that this information is neccessary? Which thirdparty? And please edit your question, or i am out

Comment: i got this library from github can see .search DataGrid in UWP u can get it .

Comment: Please provide proper XAML and code behind details and code.

Comment: hi gaurang , i share above Comment code please check it once

Comment: @Awaneesh Its not our task to search for all informations in the net. Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question

Comment: @Awaneesh , I need some more information like which third party grid you used and also how you are adding new item to it? share C# code as well.

Comment: @tanic . thanks for suggestion .i am new user in Stackoverflow so  i have no much idea how ask .so i will try improve .

Comment: @Gaurang . i got this third party from  github  please  click once this link  https://github.com/RSuter/MyToolkit/wiki/DataGrid.

Comment: @tanic : i using this third party Control .github.com/RSuter/MyToolkit/wiki/DataGrid. .please give me any suggettion  .

Comment: @Awaneesh find MtListBox control from DataGrid  template. It must be inherit from Listbox. ListBox has a ScrollIntoView method which will scroll a specified item into view. So when you add a new item, make a subsequent call to ScrollIntoView and you should be all set.

Comment: ok thanks @Gaurang .let's try .

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Additionally, it looks like `ScrollViewer` was mispelled several times in this question. Readers will appreciate it if you can double check every word in your post prior to submission, since it wastes the time of volunteers if they have to compensate for this. The computer will not tolerate code misspelling, and readers should not have to either.

Answer (score 1):

Xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" Width="400" Height="400" Background="LightGray">
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanel" SizeChanged="StackPanel_OnSizeChanged"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Code behind:

```
    private async void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
        {
            StackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock
            {
                Text = $"Item {i}",
                FontSize = 40
            });

            await Task.Delay(500);
        }
    }

    private void StackPanel_OnSizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollViewer.ChangeView(0, ScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight, 1);
    }
```

Look:

[image]

Comment: @ jet Chopper . Thanks

Comment: chopper .but this function which technology using . i am try to same but Scollerview two propety unbale to support . Changeiew or  ScrollableHeight .

Comment: I am using UWP technology .

Comment: you may find `Changeiew` method and `ScrollableHeight` property here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer. This is UWP I'm sure.

Comment: now i unable to fine these method or property .ok i seeing URL .Thanks

Comment: @JetChopper How do you relate this answer with what he asked?

Comment: Just guessed :)